# What sections are not loaded by the PE loader?

Tags: windows, loader, portable-executable

Are any sections at all *not* loaded by the PE loader? Or are every section specified in the section headers loaded? In ELF programs, it's section headers (Called program headers, or segments) that are supposed to be loaded are those that are flagged with `PT_LOAD`. Is there anything similar to that in PE programs?

PS. I found the flag `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_DISCARDABLE`. Are sections flagged with that not loaded?

Comment: that's not how it works.  The entire file gets memory mapped.  Nothing gets loaded until you access the memory page.

Comment: That's right. Nothing is loaded. Pages get loaded on demand though page faults.

Comment: So technically every single page is accessible if needed? And provide an answer that I can mark as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a relocation section is available, but the PE image does not need to be relocated, the loader does not load the relocation section. If a PE image has been digitally signed, it has a section that contains the certificate. This section is not loaded by the loader. Additionally, if a debug section is available, this is also not loaded by the loader.

Comment: Aditionnally, the DOS Stub is also not loaded. It simply simply ignored by the loader.....Some malware misuse that and put their own stuff in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Well, DOS Stub is not a Section!

As a general rule, some parts of the PE file can be read, but not mapped in memory (like relocations). And some parts are not mapped at all. Debugging information at the end of the file, is an instance of such a situation.

Usually the data placed at the end of the file -past any parts in the file (that are willing to be mapped)- are not mapped in memory.